# Floating Table for register

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of the "Floating Label"

> `enter code here` Link: https://jsbin.com/kogagudavo/

Anyone know what is the style that Gmail (Register) using ? I wanted it show the label on the exterior of the text input instead of inside.

Image

> Before: https://prnt.sc/pw63qo 
>   After: https://prnt.sc/pw63u0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't code it for you. I hope no one will because you won't learn it that way.

What you need is to make a label for that input and then position it inside the input filed to look like a placeholder.

Then on the focus of input get that label and push it up and left. It is pretty easy because I did this a few times actually. Once you get it you will see how easy are these types of animations

Tip: You can't animate placeholders in this way. Go to google and do inspect element on input and check what their code looks like

Come back with updated code so we can work it out :)